# Server to Server Large File Copy using PHP copy function

Tags: php, file, server

I want to copy some large files from one server to another server using PHP Copy. I used below PHP code for this. But some reason it not working. Actually the new file downloaded got corrupted / unable to open using ZIP application (like WinZIP, WinRAR etc.)

```
/* Source File URL */
$remote_file_url = 'http://speedtest.tele2.net/10GB.zip';
 
/* New file name and path for this file */
$local_file = 'datafile/DL-10GB.zip';
 
/* Copy the file from source url to my server */
$copy = copy( $remote_file_url, $local_file );
 
/* Add notice for success/failure */
if( !$copy ) {
    echo "Doh! failed to copy $file...\n";
}
else {
    echo "WOOT! success to copy $file...\n";
}
```

Is there any server permission issue? I am new in PHP, any answer to accomplish my task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the size of the new file correct? Can you open the new file with a text editor? Some more details please.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! New files means the downloaded ZIP file?

Comment: Exactly: The downloaded zip

Comment: Check the PHP error log, there could an useful message in there. I say this because you didn't even tell us if you got the _"Doh!"_ or the _"WOOT!"_ message. All we know is: _"it not working"_ and you seem to have copied something.

Comment: I got the message _"Doh!"_ and the ZIP file got downloaded successfully. The file size also showing its 10GB. But unable to open / Unzip. Opening this file using text editor (as @OcasoProtal said) is taking too much time. Still I am trying to open it there.